# RecyclerView on Click Listener Not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When i want to click recycler view then it should open another Activity Data is fetching but the problem is when i click on recycleview it displays nothing. 
I tried RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener. but no Success yet.
 Can You please figure it out whats the issue,where i am going wrong

```
 public class RestaurantAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
 List<AllRestaurant> restaurantList;
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //public TextView long1, medium, small;
        TextView t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;
        ImageView logo;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            t1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t1);
            t2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t2);
            t3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t3);
            t4=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t4);
            t5=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t5);
            logo=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
         //   final AllRestaurant items = getItem(position);
            //long1.setText(items.getRestaurent_id());
            // final NotifyUsers notifyUsers=new NotifyUsers(context);
            // username.setText(items.getResponse_by());


            // little.setText(items.g);

        }
    }
    public RestaurantAdapter(List<AllRestaurant> restaurantList) {
        this.restaurantList = restaurantList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        AllRestaurant restaurant = restaurantList.get(position);

        RestaurentAddress restaurentAddress=restaurant.getRestaurentAddress();
        RestaurentInfo restaurentInfo=restaurant.getRestaurentInfo();
        RestaurentSetting restaurentSetting=restaurant.getRestaurentSetting();
        User user=restaurant.getUser();
        Zone zone=restaurant.getZone();


        holder. t1.setText(restaurentInfo.getRestaurent_name());
        holder.t2.setText(restaurentAddress.getRestaurent_address1());
        holder.   t3.setText("min_pur:"+restaurentSetting.getMinimum_purcase());
        holder. t4.setText("Del In Min:"+restaurentSetting.getEstimate_delivery_time());
        String imagename=restaurentInfo.getRestaurent_logo();

        Bitmap bitmap=getImage(imagename);
        holder.logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getItemId(position);
    }
});
    /*    long1.setText(restaurentInfo.getRestaurent_name());
        little.setText(restaurentAddress.getCity_name());*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return restaurantList.size();
    }
  public Bitmap getImage(String name){
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    String url="http://ibookstay.com/oops/web/img/uploads/res_log/"+name;
    OkhttpClient clientOkHttp=new OkhttpClient();
    try {
        byte image[]=new byte[0];
      //   image=clientOkHttp.execute(url).get();
        image = clientOkHttp.execute(url).get();
        if (image != null && image.length > 0){
            bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
           // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           // tv.setText("Total btytes download: "+ image.length);
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  bitmap;
}
}
```

And This is my Fragment File :

```
public class RestaurantFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinkedList<AllRestaurant> allRestaurants;
    RestaurantAdapter allRestaurantAdapter;
    MethodModel methodModel;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurantlist, container, false);
        methodModel=new MethodModel(getActivity());
        allRestaurants=methodModel.getAllRestaurant();
        allRestaurantAdapter=new RestaurantAdapter(allRestaurants);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

// set the adapter
        recyclerView.setAdapter(allRestaurantAdapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Layout File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="desktop.oopsfood.Navigation"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_navigation">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Search For Location"
            android:id="@+id/locationget"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.99">

        </EditText>
        <requestFocus />

            android:shadowRadius="2.0"
            android:layout_weight=".3" />




    </LinearLayout>
<!--    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"></ListView>-->
    <FrameLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you check this SO question which answers your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick

Answer (score 3):

```
Using Interface you can solve your problem:

 public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position,  List<AllRestaurant> AllRestaurant);
    }
```

Implement interface in your adapter class like this.

```
 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener {
        //public TextView long1, medium, small;
        TextView t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;
        ImageView logo;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            t1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t1);
            t2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t2);
            t3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t3);
            t4=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t4);
            t5=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t5);
            logo=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            //   final AllRestaurant items = getItem(position);
            //long1.setText(items.getRestaurent_id());
            // final NotifyUsers notifyUsers=new NotifyUsers(context);
            // username.setText(items.getResponse_by());


            // little.setText(items.g);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition(), getData());
            }
        }
    }
```

Then call like that:

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
 adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position, List<UserDetails> userDetailsList) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "index --> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want on item click for recycle view
First you need to create the following class :

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener  implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

protected OnItemClickListener listener;

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

@Nullable
private View childView;

private int childViewPosition;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent event) {
    childView = view.findChildViewUnder(event.getX(), event.getY());
    childViewPosition = view.getChildPosition(childView);

    return childView != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent event) {
    // Not needed.
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

/**
 * A click listener for items.
 */
public interface OnItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Called when an item is clicked.
     *
     * @param childView View of the item that was clicked.
     * @param position  Position of the item that was clicked.
     */
    void onItemClick(View childView, int position);

    /**
     * Called when an item is long pressed.
     *
     * @param childView View of the item that was long pressed.
     * @param position  Position of the item that was long pressed.
     */
    void onItemLongPress(View childView, int position);

}

/**
 * A simple click listener whose methods can be overridden one by one.
 */
public static abstract class SimpleOnItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Called when an item is clicked. The default implementation is a no-op.
     *
     * @param childView View of the item that was clicked.
     * @param position  Position of the item that was clicked.
     */
    public void onItemClick(View childView, int position) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    /**
     * Called when an item is long pressed. The default implementation is a no-op.
     *
     * @param childView View of the item that was long pressed.
     * @param position  Position of the item that was long pressed.
     */
    public void onItemLongPress(View childView, int position) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

}

protected class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        if (childView != null) {
            listener.onItemClick(childView, childViewPosition);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
        if (childView != null) {
            listener.onItemLongPress(childView, childViewPosition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        // Best practice to always return true here.
        // http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

The in you fragment class:

```
public class RestaurantFragment extends Fragment implements     RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener{
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);




list.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), this));





.....
 }

@Override
public void onItemClick(View childView, int position) {
    // add the code for the click here
}

@Override
public void onItemLongPress(View childView, final int position) {
}
}
```

**Let me know if you need any help**

Comment: Error:(90, 79) error: incompatible types: RestaurantFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Comment: RestaurantFragment restaurantFragment =new RestaurantFragment(); getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,restaurant‌​Fragment).commit();

and app shows Unfortunately Stopped

Comment: <FrameLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"

        />

Comment: it should not be a problem, but just in case make sure the fragment imported is of type supportv4 and in the activity call getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new RestaurantFragment()).commit(); and make sure the activity is extending AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity then let me know

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i got with the help of recyclerview.addonItemTouchListener and creating Interface.

```
  public class RestaurantFragment extends Fragment {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        LinkedList<AllRestaurant> allRestaurants;
        RestaurantAdapter allRestaurantAdapter;
        MethodModel methodModel;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurantlist, container, false);
            methodModel=new MethodModel(getActivity());
            allRestaurants=methodModel.getAllRestaurant();
            allRestaurantAdapter=new RestaurantAdapter(allRestaurants);
            recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    // set the adapter
            recyclerView.setAdapter(allRestaurantAdapter);
            recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

                }
            }));
            return view;
        }

        class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{
    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, ClickListener clicklistener){

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

                Log.d("Performing Better", "onInterceptTouchEvent: "+e);
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Details.class));

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                Log.d("On Touch Event Better", "onTouchEvent: "+e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        }
        public static interface ClickListener {

            public void onClick (View view, int position);
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
        }
    }
```