# Recycler View item on Click not working even after following the listener procedure

Tags: android, view

I am Trying to start an activity from a recycler view item and followed the procedures yet the onClick is not calling in my app. I have checked the hasOnClickListeners() and that returned true. please help me.

```
public class ShopAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public List<String> shopDetails;
public View view;
public Context context;




public ShopAdapter(List<String> shopDetails){
    this.shopDetails = shopDetails;
}



@Override
public ShopAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {

   view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_single,parent,false);



    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ShopAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final String shop_description_data = "ONE";
    final String shop_name_data = "TWO";

    holder.setShopNameView(shop_name_data);
    holder.setShopInfoView(shop_description_data);
```

Here I have set the item click listener from view holder

```
    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
            Log.d("GOUSE","on Item Click");
        }
    });


}

private void startShopActivity(String shop_name_data, String shop_description_data,View view) {



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return shopDetails.size();
}




public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView shopDescView;
    private TextView shopNameView;
    private View mView;
    private ItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private CardView shopItem;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
```

Here I set the on click listener to my listener interface

```
    mView.setOnClickListener(this);
        Log.d("Listener",mView.hasOnClickListeners()+"");
    }


    public void setShopInfoView(String shopDescText){
        shopDescView = mView.findViewById(R.id.shop_info);
        shopDescView.setText(shopDescText);
    }
    public void setShopNameView(String shopNameText){
        shopNameView = mView.findViewById(R.id.shop_name);
        shopNameView.setText(shopNameText);
    }

    public void startShop(String shopName,String shopDesc){
        Intent shopActivityMainIntent = new Intent(mView.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
        shopActivityMainIntent.putExtra("shopName",shopName);
        shopActivityMainIntent.putExtra("shopDescription",shopDesc);
        mView.getContext().startActivity(shopActivityMainIntent);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
        Log.d("GOUSE","set item listener");
        this.onItemClickListener = itemClickListener;

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("GOUSE","set item clicked");
        onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(view,getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView on Click Listener Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280174/recyclerview-on-click-listener-not-working)

Comment: not a duplicate sir. the answers are my question. I had done the same thing but nothing happens. if you can please help me.

Comment: You can try giving on click listner on cardview instead this. just findViewById of cardview and in onBind holder.cardview.setOnclickListner

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in adapter used interface to handle recycler view click event like below code ...

```
    private onItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

/**
 * this interface is used to handle recycler view click event.
 */
public interface onItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Cricketer cricketer);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Cricketer cricketer = mCricketerList.get(position);
    holder.mTvTitle.setText(cricketer.getName());
    holder.mTvDescription.setText(cricketer.getCountry());
    holder.mTvDate.setText(cricketer.getDateOfBirth());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(cricketer);
        }
    });
}
```

when you bind adapter into recycler view that time get click event like below code..

```
  /**
 * this method used to bind adapter into recycler view.
 */
private void setAdapter() {
    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mCricketerList);
    mRvData.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Cricketer cricketer) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cricketer Name::" + cricketer.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```